# How to Bake a Displacement / Height Map from a High Poly to a Low Poly Mesh?

Tags: mesh, texture-baking, baking, displacement, bump

I have this mesh with 7.5 million vertices:

[image: high poly mesh]

And I also have a low poly version of it with 5 thousand vertices:

[image: low poly mesh]

**I just want to bake the detailed height information of the high poly model into a displacement map that I can use on the low poly model**. Baking a normal map works just fine, but there is not option for baking actual height information:

[image: baking options]

I found out that I can enable "Experimental" feature set for Cycles and then I have a "Displacement" option under "Bake from Multires". But there is not option to bake from selected to active, what I need.

[image: baking options]

#### If this is not possible in Blender what are my options?

## Update 1

As suggested by [Manu Järvinen](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/8282/manu-j%C3%A4rvinen) I have tried using Blender 2.7 to do the displacement baking, but after baking is done I get a single-colored texture:

[image: plain texture]

Initially I though this is an issue with the "Distance" but changing it does not help.

Comment: In 2.79, have you checked normals and/or tried with a bigger back distance?

Comment: Yeah all normals should point in the right directions (event baking a normal map works perfectly fine) and if you mean the distance under the "Selected to active" checkbox: yes I tried several values without any better result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use Blender 2.79b for baking the displacement until it is available in 2.8x

https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/

Thanks for sending the .blend - it seems that your model was too small

[image]

So, when I scaled it to be roughly dimensions x=15, y=12 and z=8 and then applied the scales for both objects <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, the baking was successful with the values Distance: 0 and Bias: 0

And, you get even greater results if you scale it then with 10 and apply the scales.

Comment: Do you know why they removed it from Blender 2.8?

Comment: Not really. My guess is that they are going to add it when they find time - maybe it wasn't a piece of cake to port it from 2.79....

Comment: Ok makes sense :)

Comment: For some reason the baking outputs a one-colored texture. Do you know why? (I've updated my question for more details)

Comment: For me it seems to work: https://i.imgur.com/9JCi7Kp.png - make sure you've checked '32bit' when you create a new texture. And it seems it's okay if distance is 0. Also, it makes sense to reset the scales of the objects: Ctrl+A

Comment: I've check 32 Bit, could I text your privately to send you the blender file?

Comment: Awesome! You will here from me in a few minutes :)

Comment: I deleted the comment with my e-mail, just in case