# How to create displacement map from hair?

Tags: texture-baking, hair, displacement

I'm trying to model a sculpture. My end goal is to have a very low-poly control mesh with a displacement map (obviously, lots of subdivision applied via modifier). Rather than using hair sculpting brushes, I wanted to experiment with Blender's hair (particle) system to produce something more random than what you would get with canned sculpting brushes.

**How can I convert hair to a displacement map?**

Obviously, I'm going to lose overhangs and probably some resolution, but that's actually desired since I'm trying to make a *sculpture*, which wouldn't have overhangs anyway.

Note: I am using Blender 3.3.

Comment: Maybe related https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/278089/2214