# Clean up unseen geometry

Tags: mesh, geometry

I have this geometry and I want to keep only the exterior face. How can I get rid of the geometry that is not seen ?
The file is [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d618c1b08b4e11c211a59e8f7ca2169520231016072000/93ee897e7297b1853930fdd8c26483b220231016072021/50a8f2)
First image is with face that I want to keep and secon is with geometry that is behind face ...and want to get rid of it.
Thanks[image: Face that I want to keep]

[image: Geometry behind face and want to delete]

Comment: just curious, how have you created this?

Comment: The model consists of several "shells". If you extrude them along the Y-axis, you can make this a solid block. Then either do several boolean operations or a remesh operation. The result is a "block". The verts can be decimated to about 60k. If you just want to keep the "front faces" you can delete the faces of the back.

Comment: Is not made by me, is bought from some website...and I am not very good with Blender so please explain step by step.

Answer (score 0):

There is not simple direct way

- the proper way is manually retopology ... like [1D_Inc mastered](https://www.youtube.com/@1DInciner/videos)  ... you can help your self with "Retopoflow" addon
- quick hack with some distortions can be done with cylinder segment with Subdivision modifiers and Shrinkwrap ...

[image]

... than use Decimate modifier or if you create a manifold object from it you can search for "Quadriflow Remesher" operator.

- I haven't try with your model but the best hack (theoreticaly) could be bake **Point Position map** and use it for Displacement modifier. For more info [see this Answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/279349/2214)